# Can I hide multiple rows based on a word in a cell outside of those rows?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, ms-office

In Excel, I am trying to automatically hide rows if a cell contains certain information. The cell containing the conditional information is outside of the rows I want to hide (a cell at the top of a column). I want to do this multiple times in the same sheet.

Is there a formula, macro, code, or action I can use to accomplish this?

The following is an example of the kind of if statements I need to accomplish within the same sheet:

If CELL I1 CONTAINS “LLC” or “Limited Liability Company” or “limited liability company” or “llc”, etc. , HIDE ROWS 15,16,17, and 18.

If CELL I1 CONTAINS “Partnership” or “part”, etc., HIDE ROWS 15, 16, 19, and 20.

If CELL K1 CONTAINS “LLC” or “limited liability company”, etc., HIDE ROWS 27, 28, 29, and 30.

If CELL K1 CONTAINS “Partnership” or “part”, etc., HIDE ROWS 27, 28, 31, and 32.

This sounds so simple to me but I cannot figure out a way to do it and none of the ways online work or are quite right for the particular action I want to do.

Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like you'd need VBA for this - look at the `Worksheet_Change` event perhaps, or the `Worksheet_Calculate` event if the cell's value depends on a formula.  See "Related" questions on the right of this page.

Comment: What will that cell contain to trigger the 'hide row' maco (the only way you can really do this) - eg. would it contain the row number you want to hide-  or will it have part of the text that comprises the cell corresponding to the row you want to hide? or will it say "blank" then the macro will hide any row for which there is a blank corresponding to the column list in question? screenshot wouldn't hurt btw.  more detail bro - too many guess required on my part to make it feasible to help you ta

Comment: I lie - if you don't mind filtering the reuslts to *exclude* the row you don't want - then you don't need a macro - a little more detail on what the conditional info looks like would help mate... have you considered slicers as another option altogether - that can operate on multiple fields - but again, I sound like broken record- GIVE US detail RE: the condition - cell contents, exact match/not match/partial match; or cell reference e.g. 'row7', 8, 10 etc...??

Comment: @TimWilliams Just realized I do have VBA! I'll look into events and see if there's anything that could help. Thanks

Comment: @JB-007 The cell would contain a word/words not included in the rows I want to hide. The info is sensitive but I'll work on getting an example. Thanks

Comment: @JB-007 Here is an example of the kind of if statements I need to accomplish within the same sheet:   

If CELL I1 CONTAINS “LLC” or “Limited Liability Company” or “limited liability company” or “llc”, etc. , HIDE ROWS 15,16,17, and 18.   

If CELL I1 CONTAINS “Partnership” or “part”, etc., HIDE ROWS 15, 16, 19, and 20.   

If CELL K1 CONTAINS “LLC” or “limited liability company”, etc., HIDE ROWS 27, 28, 29, and 30.   

If CELL K1 CONTAINS “Partnership” or “part”, etc., HIDE ROWS 27, 28, 31, and 32.

Comment: darn - only had 5-10 mins so went about doing it based upon assumption that it would something a lot simpler than compound criteria....  may be able to update tom if no better soln exists...

Comment: @JB-007 Sorry about that :( I'm still looking through your code/example and seeing if there's a way it could work. Appreciate ur time!

Comment: you're not going to be able to squeeze criteria like these examples into single cell - not unless you go to town and back to try and sift each one out or incorporate within some kind of function/separeate lists--- that's a bigger job than 5-10 mins I'm afraid..

Comment: Thumbs up/upvote if my 2nd soln works - if not - vote down for th benefit of future users.

Answer (score 1):

Screenshot/[link](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j9hK9uJPbNf2CVyTXusQ?e=4gmmii) refers:

---

**Code**

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    On Error Resume Next
    Range("Table1").AutoFilter.Clear
    
    Range("Table1").AutoFilter
    
    ActiveSheet.Range("Table1").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="0"
End Sub
```

---

**Filter column:**

```
=MIN(1,SUM(--ISNUMBER(MATCH(G4:M4,$G$2:$M$2,0))))
```

[image: Filter column formula]

Caveat: per comments, depends heavily upon what exactly your so-called 'conditions' are mate.

---

**Gif/in action**

[image: representation]

Answer (score 1):

Ahh - no one else up for this one it seems - lazy days!

Ok try this out -

Screenshots/functions refer:

```
=SUM(--ISNUMBER(MATCH(ROW(M7)-ROW($M$7)+1,--TEXTSPLIT(ARRAYTOTEXT(FILTER($P$2:$P$5,--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TRANSPOSE($I$6:$L$6),$O$2:$O$5)))),","),0)))
```

Is your indicator/helper to include in table - this relies on the key comprising special names / words and rows to hide :

[image: function + key]

Then macro is as simple as filtering out the 1s- which will in effect hide the desired row should the criteria you specified be satisfied.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("I6: L6")) Is Nothing Then
        ActiveSheet.Calculate
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="0"
    End If
    
End Sub
```

---

Note that you'll want to put this macro in the code section for the sheet itsel as oppose to a separate module ---

i.e. this is going into code section for sheet 1 per :

[image: "change" code]

*What this means is that whenever you change the headings it will upate the filter for you automatically-  you can have a play around with code to achieve the same for the rows that you want to hide in the key / key itself (just select the appropriate range in the VBA code)*

Caveats : this isn't bullet proof unortunately - you may need to watch out for substring words that may tigger trigger a flase flag - haven't tested to this degree at this point I'm afraid - hopefully it works adequately well.

[image: gif illustration]

Answer (score 0):

For example, using `Select Case`

```vb
Sub HideShow()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data") 'for example
    
    ws.Range("A15:A20").EntireRow.Hidden = False 'unhide first
    Select Case LCase(ws.Range("I1").Value)
        Case "llc", "limited liability company"
            ws.Range("A15:A18").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Case "partnership", "part"
            ws.Range("A15:A16,A19:A20").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End Select
    
    ws.Range("A27:A32").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Select Case LCase(ws.Range("K1").Value)
        Case "llc", "limited liability company"
            ws.Range("A27:A30").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Case "partnership", "part"
            ws.Range("A27:A28,A31:A32").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End Select

End Sub
```